# Расширяемая Windows служба

Tags: c#, .net, windows, служба

Хочу сделать расширяемую Windows службу, которая при своем запуске динамически загружает Dll.

Каждая Dll будет представлять собой определенное задание, которое должно выполняться по расписанию.

Есть следующие вопросы:

1. Кому лучше дать ответственность за выполнение задания по расписанию самой службе или объекту задания?
2. Правильно ли вынести конфигурацию заданий в отдельный XML файл, а в app.config хранить адрес этого файла, а потом его передавать в конструкторы нужного задания, что бы объект сам себя искал там и конфигурировал?
3. Можно ли будет на ходу заменять библиотеки расширений(например, на обновленную версию) без отключения или мне не дадут заменить, используемые библиотеки?
4. Имеет ли смысл использовать MEF?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Кому лучше дать ответственность за выполнение задания по расписанию самой службе или объекту задания?

Если все расширения являются заданиями, то имеет смысл вынести код планировщика выполнения заданий в основную службу, хотя-бы для того, чтобы не дублировать его в каждом расширении.

> 2. Правильно ли вынести конфигурацию заданий в отдельный XML файл, а в app.config хранить адрес этого файла, а потом его передавать в конструкторы нужного задания, что бы объект сам себя искал там и конфигурировал?

Я бы сделал хранение настроек отдельными файлами для каждого задания в фиксированной папке или БД и передавал параметры в конструктор. Но можно использовать и ваш вариант. В любом случае, расширение должно уметь обрабатывать ситуацию, когда оно добавлено, но конфигурация  отсутствует.

> 3. Можно ли будет на ходу заменять библиотеки расширений(например, на обновленную версию) без отключения или мне не дадут заменить, используемые библиотеки?

Загруженная в CLR сборка может быть выгружена только вместе с доменом, в который загружена. Это решается загрузкой сборок-расширений в отдельный `AppDomain`, и выгрузкой этого изолированного домена, перед удалением DLL. Вообще про этот механизм лучше отдельный вопрос задать, там много нюансов, которые нужно учитывать.

> 4. Имеет ли смысл использовать MEF?

Да, этот механизм именно для таких случаев и предназначен

Comment: опоздал с написанием  :( +1